# Why does peak memory usage increase when there are more elements to loop/apply over?

Tags: r, memory, memory-management, garbage-collection, apply

I am trying to reduce the memory footprint of an R package and have noticed behaviour that I can't seem to suppress.  See the below example:

```
x <- matrix(runif(1.5e7), ncol = 200)

## CASE 1: Test with half of columns
gc(reset = TRUE)
a <- apply(x[, 1:100], 2, quantile)
gc()
#            used  (Mb) gc trigger  (Mb) max used  (Mb)
# Ncells   190549  10.2     407500  21.8   222055  11.9
# Vcells 15292303 116.7   35490421 270.8 35484249 270.8
object.size(a)
# 4696 bytes
rm(a)

## CASE 2: Test with all columns
gc(reset = TRUE)
b <- apply(x, 2, quantile)
gc()
#            used  (Mb) gc trigger  (Mb) max used  (Mb)
# Ncells   190824  10.2     407500  21.8   245786  13.2
# Vcells 15293740 116.7   39292189 299.8 39286529 299.8
object.size(b)
# 8696 bytes
rm(b)

## CASE 3: Test with all columns + call gc
gc(reset = TRUE)
c <- apply(x, 2, function(i) { r <- quantile(i); gc(); r })
gc()
#           used  (Mb) gc trigger  (Mb) max used  (Mb)
# Ncells   191396  10.3     407500  21.8   197511  10.6
# Vcells 15294307 116.7   45737818 349.0 30877185 235.6
object.size(c)
# 8696 bytes
rm(c)
```

`a` and `b` differ by only ~4kb yet the garbage collector reports a difference of ~30mb between the peak memory usage of cases 1 and 2.  `c` uses less memory than both `a` and `c`, I imagine not without a considerable penalty in runtime.

The peak memory allocation seems to positively correlate with the number of columns considered in the call to `apply`, but why?  Does the call to `apply` result in memory allocation living beyond the scope of an iteration?  I would have expected any internal temporaries to be freed (or marked as being unused) by the `gc` before the end of each iteration.

This behaviour can be reproduced using `lapply` over `data.frame`s and also with different functions in lieu of `quantile`.

I am under the impression that I am overlooking a very fundamental aspect of memory usage behaviour in `R` but still can't wrap my head around it.  Ultimately, my question is: how do I further reduce the memory footprint in cases like the example above?

Thanks in advance and do not hesitate to point out any inaccuracies in my question.

EDIT:

As per @ChristopherLouden's suggestion, I used calls to `mem` in place of `gc` and all three cases were described as taking ~126.9182mb.

```
##  http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html#garbarge-collection
mem <- function() {
  bit <- 8L * .Machine$sizeof.pointer
  if (!(bit == 32L || bit == 64L)) {
    stop("Unknown architecture", call. = FALSE)
  }

  node_size <- if (bit == 32L) 28L else 56L

  usage <- gc()
  sum(usage[, 1] * c(node_size, 8)) / (1024 ^ 2)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this sentence from the [Memory Chapter of Advanced R Programming](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html#garbarge-collection) by Hadley Wickham best summarizes the reason for the discrepancy.

> Garbage collection normally happens lazily: R calls gc() when it needs more space. In reality, that R might hold onto the memory after the function has terminated, but it will release it as soon as it's needed

The chapter also has a good function called `mem()` that allows you to see more clearly how much memory a block of code is using than `gc()` allows.  If time allows, I would redo the test with Wickham's `mem()` function.

**Edit:**
As Peter noted, the `mem()` function is deprecated.  Use the `mem_used()` function from the **pryr** package instead.

Comment: The function is no longer in the book, but is now included in the pryr package as mem_used().

Comment: @PeterVerbeet: Thank you.  I have updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Sure, @Christopher-Louden. Please note that it is in the "pryr" package, not "plyr" (just 1 character difference...). The pryr package has lots more cool stuff to see what's going on. For instance, I use "address(x)" a lot to find the memory location of object x. This is very useful in checking whether x is modified in place (--> same memory location before and after the manipulation of x), or whether it is copied by x before making the modification (--> x's memory location will be different after the manipulation).